# Java playwright usage of page.waitForFunction()

Tags: java, playwright, playwright-java

I am trying to figure out how to use the `page.waitForFunction()` in Playwright in Java.

I would like for a `page.evaluate()` to run first, and for the `page.waitForFunction()` to wait on it, before continuing.

I have the following:
`page.waitForFunction(() => page.evaluate("document.readyState").equals("complete"));`

But syntactically that is incorrect or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this please ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a string to the `waitForFunction`

```
page.waitForFunction("() => page.evaluate('document.readyState').equals('complete')");
```